# How to include custom graphics layers in Esri ArcGIS print task

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have an Esri map, and a print task service, After loading the map, I have added custom graphics on my map, but when I tried to take the screenshot by using JavaScript Print Task (**esri.tasks.PrintTask**), it is only printing the default map same as it is ArcGIS Server, not printing the programmatically added custom graphics. Here is my code.

```
this.exportWebMap=function(url,map,width,height){

        var deferred = new Deferred();
        var printTask = new PrintTask(url);
        var attrs={};       
        var template = new PrintTemplate();
        var mapWidth=map&&map.width?map.width:this.currentMap.width;
        var mapHeight=map&&map.height?map.height:this.currentMap.height;
        template.exportOptions = {
            width: mapWidth,
            height: mapHeight,
            dpi: 96 
        };
        template.format = "JPG";
        template.layout = "MAP_ONLY",
        template.preserveScale = false;
        template.showLabels = true;
        template.showAttribution = false;

        template.layoutOptions = {
            "legendLayers": [], // empty array means no legend
            "scalebarUnit": "Miles",
            "copyrightText": "<div>xxx</div>",
        }
        var params = new PrintParameters();

        params.map = map||this.currentMap;
        params.template = template;

        printTask.execute(params, function(success){
            deferred.resolve(success);
        }, 
        function(error){
            deferred.resolve(error);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Print Task JSON

```
{
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
    "features": [{
        "geometry": {
            "rings": [
                [
                    [1394673.6791358888, 433055.85258604586],
                    [1394680.201104477, 433069.9998674691],
                    [1394686.46519956, 433083.3777934611],
                    [1394691.6935355663, 433094.899095878],
                    [1394704.8713307232, 433089.2193172127],
                    [1394716.3017540574, 433084.7445886284],
                    [1394727.1435958892, 433080.7009615451],
                    [1394739.709843725, 433076.03791312873],
                    [1394732.3896483928, 433060.93656538427],
                    [1394724.798128143, 433045.49433904886],
                    [1394720.2138197273, 433035.48615697026],
                    [1394708.6295253038, 433040.35196088254],
                    [1394698.9999513924, 433044.4631731361],
                    [1394688.3766130656, 433049.2423630506],
                    [1394677.6417263895, 433053.9851357192],
                    [1394673.6791358888, 433055.85258604586]
                ]
            ],
            "spatialReference": {
                "wkid": 102723,
                "latestWkid": 3735
            }
        },
        "symbol": {
            "color": [255, 26, 26, 255],
            "width": 1,
            "type": "esriSLS",
            "style": "esriSLSSolid"
        }
    }]
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems like you are using **SimpleLineSymbol** for polygon geometry instead use **"SimpleFillSymbol"** and try, the JSON would look like as mentioned below

```
{
"geometryType": "esriGeometryPolygon",
"features": [{
    "geometry": {
        "rings": [
            [
                [1394673.6791358888, 433055.85258604586],
                [1394680.201104477, 433069.9998674691],
                [1394686.46519956, 433083.3777934611],
                [1394691.6935355663, 433094.899095878],
                [1394704.8713307232, 433089.2193172127],
                [1394716.3017540574, 433084.7445886284],
                [1394727.1435958892, 433080.7009615451],
                [1394739.709843725, 433076.03791312873],
                [1394732.3896483928, 433060.93656538427],
                [1394724.798128143, 433045.49433904886],
                [1394720.2138197273, 433035.48615697026],
                [1394708.6295253038, 433040.35196088254],
                [1394698.9999513924, 433044.4631731361],
                [1394688.3766130656, 433049.2423630506],
                [1394677.6417263895, 433053.9851357192],
                [1394673.6791358888, 433055.85258604586]
            ]
        ],
        "spatialReference": {
            "wkid": 102723,
            "latestWkid": 3735
        }
    },
    "symbol": {
        "color": [155,
            187,
            89,
            128
        ],
        "outline": {
            "color": [115,
                140,
                61,
                255
            ],
            "width": 1.5,
            "type": "esriSLS",
            "style": "esriSLSSolid",
            "marker": null
        },
        "type": "esriSFS",
        "style": "esriSFSSolid"
    }
}]
```

}

Comment: Kudos , You made my day, I was using SimpleLineSymbol to draw polygon. And when i changed it to SimpleFillSymbol , I've got exact web map as printed with added polygons on the map.                
    this.symbol= new SimpleLineSymbol();
    this.symbol.setColor(new Color([255,255,0,1]));  changed to this               this.polySymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,new Color([255, 26, 26, 1]),2),new Color([255, 26, 26, 0]));

Comment: happy to hear, cheers!!!